# Limit number of boxes checked when arrays are involved

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm pretty amateurish when it comes to JavaScript stuff, so I apologize if this question comes off as a bit dumb.

I'm currently trying to code something that involves forms with a limit on how many checkboxes can be selected. The method I've come across that has worked best for my purposes so far is the one detailed here:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/checkboxlimit.shtml

It works for the most part but I run into an issue when checkboxes need to output an array. For example, if I write the input line as:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="One" /> One<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="Two" /> Two<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="choice[]" value="Three" /> Three<br />
```

I've tried quite a few things but I can't figure out how to change the code so that it works with the brackets in the input's name field.

Comment: Should a group of checkboxes like that count as one, or as three checkboxes when the total is limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that script [above](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/checkboxlimit.shtml), you can change it into using `.elements` to get the group of elements and applying that same custom function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Syntax: checkboxlimit(checkbox_reference, limit)

var world_form = document.forms.choices; // the form
var my_checkboxes = world_form.elements['choice[]']; // check boxes
checkboxlimit(my_checkboxes, 2);

</script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbnjuehd/)

Comment: @user1443628 sure glad this helped

Answer (score 2):

Couple things here:

1. The tutorial references checkboxlimit(document.forms.world.countries, 2). This will not work with []. You can use [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
2. It doesn't look like this will work as expected if you uncheck a box because it works on 'onclick', and never increases the number of checked boxes.

I've adapted the code in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ad8t5sju/

What I changed:

```
  var elems = form.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
```

I used `getElementsByClassName` here so that we can easily fetch the checkboxes that are the particular form's children. `HTMLElement` only has `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName` unfortunately, so we can't easily use names here.

```
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
if (elems[i].checked) {
    ++count;
}
```

You'll see here that I take into account the already checked boxes. That way if you have 1 checked by default, you can check another 4 if your limit is 5.

```
 elems[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.checked) {

    if (count + 1 > limit) {
        alert ("no more than " + limit + " must be checked");
      this.checked = false;
      return false;
    }
    ++count;
  } else {
    --count;

    if (count < 0) {
        count = 0;
    }
  }
});
```

Here, instead of adding 0 when a box is being unchecked, we reduce the count. That's so the same box won't count twice if we untick and tick again.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and easy way**

```
<form id="world" name="world">
    <input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" /> USA<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" /> Canada<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" /> Japan<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" /> China<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" /> France<br />
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
        var limit = 2;
        if($("[type='checkbox']:checked").length > limit)
        {
            alert("You can only select a maximum of "+limit+" checkboxes")
            this.checked=false;
        }
    });
    </script>
```